# ceiling fan oil leak

Tags: ceiling-fan

Lately, when I've been leaving papers out on my desk, some weird yellow-ish grease stains appear on it after a while. After doing a bit of research about what could cause my problem, I found out that it was probably my ceiling fan. How would I go about fixing an oil leak from my fan?

Comment: A leak usually means a seal has gone bad.  If right seal can be found, replacement of it.

Answer (score 3):

If anyone has been oiling the fan, have them stop doing it. If no one's been oiling it, the the seals on the bearing have probably disintegrated and the oil is leaking out. Not really a way to fix this because matching or repairing the bearings would be next to impossible. The oil will continue to leak until it's gone and then the fan will start to make noise and have to be replaced.

Comment: If you're really good with mechanics, you could probably disassemble the fan, find the bearings, pull any oil seals, find replacement bearings and oil seals, then install them, but yeah, replacement is probably a better bet. ;)